# Use of --symlink-install

Tags: ros, ros2, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When we use `--symlink-install` for a build, that means the changes made in the source files would be reflected in the install files automatically ? Is this correct ?

If I change a source code in the source directory and save and run the node using `ROS2 run` command, would it be reflected ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296081/use-of---symlink-install/) by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 667 on 2018-07-03

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2018-07-03**:
Related #q296083

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Generally yes, but that's only true for interpreted languages. Compiled languages need to be recompiled to take effect.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-07-04**:
yes, I meant `python` for example.

**Comment by [Hongbo Miao](https://answers.ros.org/users/4114/hongbo-miao/) on 2022-12-24**:
Just make it more clear for future people, `--symlink-install` applies for languages such as Python, but not for languages such as C++.